# What is the grammar modification needed to accept given arithmetic expression, and probability of parser to fail (loop) for the given expression

Tags: parsing

Have a regular grammar, having two classes of operators: addop, mulop, with precedence (addop)
< precedence(mulop); & left-to-right associativity:

```
expr -> expr + term | expr - term | term
term -> term * factor | term / factor | factor
factor -> factor digit | digit
digit -> 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

Arithmetic expression:

```
200+300+400-50*10/5*2-60+100*10
```

The arithmetic expression's evaluation need yield a result similar to C compiler, i.e.  1640; but using top-down parsing.
The precedence & left-to-right associativity rules imply, the below processing, as indicated by parenthesis:

```
((200+300)+400)-(((50*10)/5)*2)-60+(100*10)
=> 900-(200)-60+1000
=> 900-260+1000
=> 1640
```

But, constructing parse tree for the above expression, with the given grammar, is not possible, as once the second rule is triggered, cannot revert back to the first rule back.

So, do I need to modify the grammar to enable parsing, say as:

```
expr -> expr + term | expr - term | term
term -> term * factor | term / factor | factor | expr
factor -> factor digit | digit
digit -> 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

Edit: As per inputs by @sepp2k, have built the derivation corresponding to the parse tree, using the first grammar. Kindly vet the same.

Also, request hint on finding the **probability** of the infinite recursion problem arising, for this left-recursive grammar, for top-down parsing, of the given string of arithmetic expression.
By probability, mean the ratio of chances for the grammar processing the above string, going into infinite loop; divided by the average number of attempts to correctly parse the given arithmetic expression.

I hope the numerator would be equal to the number of times a NT apart from digit is processed. But, clueless for finding out the average number of times the top-down parser runs.

Arithmetic expression:

```
200+300+400-50*10/5*2-60+100*10

expr -> expr + term 
=> expr - term + term 
=> expr - term - term + term
=>...=> expr+term+term-term -term+term
=> term + term + term - term - term+term 
=> factor + term +...- term+term 
=>...=> 900-term-term+term 
=> 900-term*factor-term+term
=> 900-term/factor*factor-term +term
=> 900-term*factor/factor* factor-term+term
=>...=> 900 - 50 * 10 / factor * factor - term+term
=> 900-50*10/5*factor-term+term 
=> 900-500/5* factor-term+term
=> 900 - 100*factor-term+term
=>...=> 900-100*2-term+term 
=>...=> 700-term+term 
=>...=> 700-60 +term
=>...=>640 + term *factor
=>...=>640 +1000 
=> 1640
```

Comment: How is your grammar implementing "precedence (addop) < precedence(mulop)"?

Comment: @ScottHunter The first line of the grammar handles addop, which will occur above the mulop, in the parse tree.The mulop will be handled by the second line of the grammar, hence will occur below addop in the parse tree.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you saying that your first grammar would not produce the correct parse tree for the expression `200+300+400-50*10/5*2-60+100*10`? If so, which parse tree do you think it will produce instead? Or are you asking how to make it able to parse expressions with parentheses in it?

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks. The parenthesis just show the desired order of evaluation, which the parse tree would have shown instead. I want the parenthesis based order of evaluation. But, the second line of the grammar once invoked, there is no way to handle addop. So, is the modification to the grammar, as shown, correct?

Comment: @Sai As far as I can tell, your first grammar will produce exactly the parse tree you want. If you don't think it does, you'll need to explain more clearly why you think so and what you think it will produce instead. Your second grammar is ambiguous and not regular (I don't know whether the latter is relevant to you, but I'm mentioning it because you've mentioned that the original grammar is regular).

Comment: @sepp2k Kindly vet the edited post, as done at the bottom.

Comment: I'm reading the grammar and it seems to me that expr should be something more like `expr -> expr + expr | expr - expr | term`, same for term `term -> term * term | term / term | factor`. Because then expr can be either a term or another expr + expr. (Actually thinking about it more, I'd be wrong)

Comment: @Владимир That version would be ambiguous (`a - b - c` could be parsed as either `(a - b) - c` or `a - (b - c)`). OP's version is the correct way to specify a grammar for left-associative operators.

Comment: @sepp2k Request to give some hint on the probability of the above left-recursive grammar going into infinite loop. Kindly see the edit above, for details, as has been modified.