# Find the average number of times a parser attempts to construct a successful parse tree

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Is there a theoretical notion developed, for finding the average number of times a parser (preferable, top-down parser; as it can fail too, i.e. on infinite loops) attempts, with leaving a given attempt due to no further progress possible; till it finds the successful parse tree, i.e. assuming an unambiguous grammar.

Taking left-recursive grammar, having two classes of operators: addop, mulop, with precedence (addop)
< precedence(mulop); & left-to-right associativity:
:

```
expr -> expr + term | expr - term | term
term -> term * factor | term / factor | factor
factor -> factor digit | digit
digit -> 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

My assumption is that any theoretical notion, would be for a particular string (of arithmetical expression) being parsed for the given grammar.
Hence, let the arithmetic expression be:

```
200+300+400-50*10/5*2-60+100*10
```

Would consider the single possible successful parse tree, as given in derivation form, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76814007/22322013), in Edit.

Comment: LR compilers are deterministic. That is to say, they don't 'fail' at all. Depending on the grammar and the implementation, a top-down (recursive descent) parser need not fail either. Only pathological grammars requiring lots of lookahead would cause that.

Answer (score 1):

Though am only a student, in Bachelors course of CSE, but can imagine (without any inputs) that the reason for so much negative points is the fact that the top-down parse cannot be used with left-recursive grammars at all, unless the grammar is modified to remove left-recursion.

The parse tree for a top-down parser for an unmodified left-to-right recursive grammar cannot happen, and has meaning only for a modified grammar; that has left-to-right recursion removed.

The link given for the derivation of parse tree, for an arithmetic expression, for the given grammar, hence has no meaning.